# Python function: return an array without additional memory allocations

Tags: python, function, numpy, pass-by-reference

Suppose I want to make a function that multiplies input vector by input matrix:

```
def MatMul(A,b):
    return A.dot(b)
```

Now, I execute the following code:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],dtype='float64')
b=np.array([4,5,6],dtype='float64')
c=np.zeros(3,dtype='float64')
c=MatMul(A,b)
```

Will there be additional array allocation inside `MatMul` function? I know that `A` and `b` will be passed by reference. Note, that I've already preallocated array `c`.

Generally, how to avoid unnecessary preallocations in simple functions like this? Say, I want to perform several mathematical operations:

```
def Rank1Update(A,b,alpha):
    c=A.dot(b)
    c+=alpha*c.dot(c)*c
    return c
```

I can fit many mathematical functions in 1 line, but code quickly becomes unreadable.

I am familiar with C-style programming, where in order to avoid unnecessary memory allocations one would pass `A`,`b` and `c` by references and update `c` inside the functions that returns `void`. I can do the same in python, but I want to use `return` for my convenience and code readability,

Thanks,

Mikhail

Comment: When you write `c=MatMul(A,b)`, the previous value of `c` *cannot possibly have any influence on the result* - the function has no way of knowing what's going to be done with its return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy, in most of its functions that produce new arrays, has a parameter to store the resulting array. I used the names version of that parameter, `out`, in my code below, but you can leave out the name. You must make sure that the `out` array has the correct shape and dtype. The purpose of this parameter is exactly what you want--to avoid additional memory allocation. This can also speed up the code.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype='float64')
b = np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype='float64')
c = np.zeros(3, dtype='float64')

A.dot(b, out=c)
```

That parameter is mentioned in the [documentation for dot()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). If you want to change the definition of function `MatMul`,

```
def MatMul(A, b, c=None):
    return A.dot(b, out=c)
```

and change the call to

```
MatMul(A, b, c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to define a function in such way that one can call it `c=MatMul(A,b)` and without additional memory allocation?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin: Not really. The resulting matrix could have a different shape from both `A` and `b` and could be larger than both (such as multiplying a `3x1` array by a `1x3` array and getting a `3x3` array). The function `MatMul` would not know where to put the result, either in memory or binding it to a name to represent the result, and there may not even be room to store the result into one of the input parameter arrays. The only way I can see is to use a global variable in the function, which is bad programming style. Why don't you want to change the way the function is called?

Comment: `c=MatMul(A,b)` looks more intuitive and elegant (in my point of view) than `MatMul(A,b,c)`. However, the solution that you suggested works good as well

Comment: @MikhailGenkin: I agree that the assignment is more intuitive and elegant than the function call with an out parameter, but programming is full of trade-offs. I see no good way to avoid the trade-off of elegance versus memory allocation.

Comment: Just 1 more question: In C there is another solution: if a function is simple enough, one can make it inline function (meaning that compiler will take a function body and substitute it into every place where function is called). Is it possible to make this trick in Python using, say, lambda-functions?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin: Python has different goals than C. One result is that there are many fewer optimizations made to increase speed, even when those optimizations would be easy to do. (Tail recursion comes to my mind.) Lambda functions in Python do have some restrictions, but that's the closest to in-line functions that I know of. But that's not very close--in-line functions still need to be *called* and their code is not put in the place where it is called.

Comment: @MikhailGenkin: Inlining wouldn't affect the allocation behavior anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`dot` doesn't know or care about the `c` variable or the array that variable already holds a reference to. It'll make a new array, and `=` will bind the `c` variable to that new array, leaving the old array to be cleaned up by the memory management system.

If you want `dot` to store output into an existing array, you need to tell it to do that:

```
A.dot(b, out=c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about function and return? Is it possible to return an array without additional memory allocation? Or should I use C-style coding: `def MatMul(A,b,c)` where I pass all three arrays to function by reference ?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin: You want the caller to communicate something to the function - specifically, where to write results. Return values do not allow communication in that direction.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected so. So, I guess, the only possible way, as suggested in the answer above, is C-style programming: pass A,b and c by reference and modify `c` inside function